# <style global jsx /> doesn't seem to be applied

Tags: reactjs, styles, jsx, next.js

I've got custom `_document` file with contents mentioned below. For some reason styles specified inside `<style global jsx />` do not seem to be applied on first render. In development they get applied when I refresh the page, but when I build my site for static export, they are not applied even after refresh.

```
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: App => props => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />)
      });

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return {
      ...initialProps,
      styles: (
        <Fragment>
          {initialProps.styles}
          {sheets.getStyleElement()}
        </Fragment>
      )
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:400,600,700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />

          <style global jsx>{`
            html {
              font-size: 16px;
            }

            a {
              text-decoration: none;
            }

            #__next {
              position: relative;
              display: flex;
            }

            #__next-prerender-indicator {
              display: none;
            }
          `}</style>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Comment: I think it is `<style jsx global>` tag and not `<style global jsx>`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an issue, same behaviour with position changed

Comment: Check this - https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/Global-styles-and-layouts

Comment: Also this - https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#global-styles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add your global style to `_app` instead. As for why it doesn't work in `_document` check this https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#server-side-rendering

I am not sure if it will work but you can ty doing

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import flush from 'styled-jsx/server';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps (ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    initialProps.styles = flush()
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:400,600,700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          />

          <style global jsx>{`
            html {
              font-size: 16px;
            }

            a {
              text-decoration: none;
            }

            #__next {
              position: relative;
              display: flex;
            }

            #__next-prerender-indicator {
              display: none;
            }
          `}</style>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}


export default MyDocument;
```

Comment: You should add your global style to _app instead - this is the right answer! Thanks @evgeni fotia!